# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment when testing divisibilty

Tags: c++, math, operators, lvalue

On c++, I want to say that if the amount entered is divisible by 20, then output the solution. However, it says that the operand for second line must be on the left. Thank you in advance!

```
  cin >> amountEntered;
  if (amountEntered / 20 = 0)
  {
    cout << amountEntered/20;
  }
```

This is reason c++ gives for the error:

```
main.cpp:16:28: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
       if (amountEntered / 20 = 0)
                                ^
```

also, if I was trying to say if the amount entered was NOT divisible by 20, is that "amountEntered / 20 == 0" ?

Comment: change `=` to `==`. A single `=` is assignment. `==` is testing for equality.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` means assignment, which causes an error because ther's nothing to assign.  Equality test is `==`.

In addition, you're doint integer arithmetic here. So anything smaller than 20 will result in 0.  So better test the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
if (amountEntered % 20 == 0)
```